# How can I use SSIS to copy data from 1000 tables in a CRM to access?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2017

I think I can use a for each container for doing this. There are multiple examples for SQL servers but not for other types. Can anyone suggest me how to do this in SSIS? (CRM doesn't have SQL database).

Comment: If the CRM has no SQL database, what kind of interfaces does it have? A web service maybe? A way to export data to a flat file?

Comment: It has a providex database. I am able to accomplish this task using Access Wizard for External Sources. However since I want to auotmate it, I think SSIS is a good option .

Comment: Does it have an ODBC driver?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: So that would be my suggestion. Use the ODBC driver. Seems like other people are also doing the same. Check [this thread on the Sage forums](https://sagecity.na.sage.com/support_communities/sage100_erp/f/sage-100-technical-and-installation-discussions/92666/ssis-package-providex-occasional-extract-issue)